# Редактирование JSON с Array

Tags: python, массивы, json, vim

В JSON файле встречаются массивы(не один). Нужно с помощью Vim or Python
или еще чего создать дубликаты это файла json но с разделением массива на более мелкие например по 20 элементов в каждом.
Например:

````
        "season": "2016/2017",
        "country": "Argentina",
        "league": "Liga Profesional",
        "championship": "Boca Juniors",
        "data": [
            "25.09.2016",
            "27.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "27.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "04.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016"
        ]
   }```
Должны получить к примеру 2 файла
``` {
        "season": "2016/2017",
        "country": "Argentina",
        "league": "Liga Profesional",
        "championship": "Boca Juniors",
        "data": [
            "25.09.2016",
            "27.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "26.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "27.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016",
            "25.09.2016"
        ]
   }

    {
        "season": "2016/2017",
        "country": "Argentina",
        "league": "Liga Profesional",
        "championship": "Boca Juniors",
        "data": [
            "03.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "04.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "03.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "02.10.2016",
            "01.10.2016"
        ]
   }
````

Comment: Именно  vim? Python подойдёт лучше. Или это учебное задание?

Comment: Python вполне сойдет. Задание не учебное. Есть база json файлов и надо её разбить на более мелкие для более быстрой загрузке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример адаптирован под ваш формат json.

```
#  json_data - ваш json, n - по сколько записей разбивать
def divide_json(json_data: dict ,n: int = 5):
    kek = [json_data['data'][i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(json_data['data']), n)]
    for i in kek:
        a['data'] = i
        yield a
```